# MS Access: INSERT INTO statement returning a syntax error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't figure out the error. I already tried adding more parentheses but this didn't help. This code checks to see if there is already a query called "InsertFilmZip" and if there isn't one, it creates it with the given statement. For some reason, it's saying that there is a `Run-time error 3139: Syntax error in PARAMETER clause` but I can't find the error.

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()

    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    Dim query As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String
    Dim item_val As String

    item_val = Me.Text314

    For Each query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
      If query.Name = "InsertFilmZip" Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next query

    If query Is Nothing Then
      sql = "parameters " & "P1 Number" & _
        "INSERT INTO [tbl_FilmZipInfo] " & _
        "(qty_per_unit) " & _
        " VALUES ([P1])" & _
        "WHERE (((tbl_FilmZipInfo.qty_per_unit)='" & Me.Text314 & "'))"
      Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("InsertFilmZip", sql)
    End If

    query.Parameters("P1").Value = Me.Text317

    query.Execute

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL doesn't make sense, so try this adjustment:

```
  sql = "parameters P1 Long;" & _
    "UPDATE [tbl_FilmZipInfo] " & _
    "SET qty_per_unit = [P1] " & _
    "WHERE qty_per_unit = " & Me.Text314 & ""
```